# Understanding Multiple-linear regression and using python to accomplish this?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I am wondering what package/library would be best suited for preforming multiple-linear regression. I've read about it but the concept still confuses me. Currently I am trying to preform MLR on two files I have one is something called a Shapefile  this is basically like a vector image with a lot of data about a particular data. Another is a raster image of that same state which has a lot of associated data about the state and number of pixels, areas, things like that. What I am trying to do is preform multiple linear regression on the three variables I have:

1. impervious surface
2. developed class
3. planted/cultivated class.

The instructions I have ask me to:

"Perform multiple linear regression between population density and area percentage of the following surface covers and calculate the R2 of the regression"

I'm not sure what this means. When I asked for further clarificatio, thinking it was doing combinations of those three variables and correlating it with a variable called Population_desnity, from an associate I was told this:

"By multiple regression, I don't mean to run three regressions separately, with each one using one independent variable. A multiple regression is one regression with any number of independent variables, not just two only. For this project, you need to use with three independent variables in each regression. Search the internet to understand what what is a multiple linear regression if you don't have a good understanding of it yet."

I need help understanding MLR in this context and how I would go about programming it into python.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ since it seems you first need to understand what multiple linear regression is before worrying about how to write a program.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions here - one is about the concept of multiple linear regression (commonly referred to as 'linear regression', since 'simple linear regression' is quite a trivial problem and less useful). You might have more luck with the conceptual question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ explaining your problem there. The second question is about how to implement multiple linear regression in Python - I would have a look at the implementations in the `scipy` and `sklearn` libraries. Both are well documented.

Comment: statistical models in python are typically run using the `statsmodels` package (although there are others). You can find many multiple regression implementation examples on this site. But like others have mentioned, your best bet is to understand the concept before trying to implement it